# Reflected client actions from a different computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm working on my new blog, for now the server side is NodeJS(**using expressjs**), I host the server on my computer.

For rapid development I'm using GulpJS.

Before I explain the **weird** thing. Let me say that both ports(**3000 and 80 are open**).

- Gulp version: `3.9.0`
- NodeJS version: `0.10.35`
- Browser-sync: `2.7.12`

This is my `index.js`, I use `node index.js` to start the server.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('base', '/public');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.sendfile('index.html');

});

var server = app.listen(80, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app istening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Now this is the important part from `gulpfile.js` I use(I removed most tasks for simplicity):

```
var sync = require("browser-sync").create();
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    sync.init({
        proxy: "http://localhost:80",
        browser: "chrome",
        port: 3000
    });
});
```

So after I work a while on the my blog I decided to show it to a friend, while the `NodeJS` server is running and `Gulp` is watching over some `html`, `js` and `sass` files, I send my `domain.ml:3000` to my friend, the domain points to my external IP and the port `3000` is due to the proxy defined via the `gulpfile.js`.

**The weird thing I can't explain:**

While my friend played with the website his actions were reflected to me, meaning we both visited `domain.ml:3000` and **when he** clicked a link with `src` attribute set to `#`, on **my side** the url changed to `domain.ml:3000/#`, I also have a link that when clicked opens a tab(the transition is made by some **js**+**css transitions**) and again when the tab opens on **his side** it also opens on **my side**.

I'm thinking it's something with the `browser-sync` proxy but I can't explain nor understand this behavior, if anyone can help me figure it I'll be very thankful, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the deal, browser-sync is sending the hash url via your proxy to your server (as you click links with '#') that fragment has a somewhat different treatment.

The server on port 80 is now a puppet replaying all URLS from your browser-sync session, you are both connected on browser-sync port 3000, when one of you sends in a hash change, you both receive the new location as you server on port:80 now also has the new location.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer, I think I pretty much understand now, but do you think you can explain a bit further or direct me to some reliable sources so I can read myself, any more info are will help me to better grasp the idea.

Answer (score 3):

That's basically what browser-sync is meant to do. You can sync browsers to test the same app simultaneously. That will change once you make a gulp build and serve that build, instead of your 'dev version'.